How to disable auto-recognition of .js files as TypeScript compilation output in IntelliJ IDEA
I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA and working on a project that uses both JavaScript and TypeScript. I'm facing an issue where IntelliJ automatically recognizes .js files as compiled output of .ts files when they have the same name.
What is the current method to disable the automatic recognition of .js files as TypeScript compilation output in the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA?
Example: Let's say I have the following files in my project:
src/
  ├── example.ts
  └── example.js

When I open example.js, I see a message at the top of the file saying "Excluded from compilation". This indicates that IntelliJ IDEA is treating this .js file as a compilation output of the .ts file, which is not what I want.
What I want to achieve:
I want IntelliJ IDEA to treat both .ts and .js files as separate, editable source files, without automatically assuming the .js file is a compiled output.

Why must they have the same name?

Why create them in the same folder?

That's how the existing system i'm working with is set up.
This is how the existing convention is organized, so i can't do anything about it right now.
